# HttpGuzzle 6, Post Request With Data and File

Tags: symfony, curl, guzzle, php-7.2, guzzle6

I'm trying to POST a request with a file and some fields, Before i was using v3 of Guzzle http and below code was working,

```php
        $client = Client();
        $request = $client->request('POST', $url, ['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'auth_trusted_header')]]);

        /** @var \GuzzleHttp\Post\PostBody $body */
        $body = $request->getBody();
        $body->setField('authorId', $user->getId());
        $body->setField('context', 'avatar');
        $body->addFile(
            new PostFile(
                'file',
                fopen('data://text/plain;base64,'.$avatar, 'r'),
                $user->getId().'.png'
            )
        );
        try {
            $response = $client->send($request);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = false;
        }
```

> After upgrade to V6, i update the below code but somehow it's not working....

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzleRequest;

        $client = new Client();
        $request = new GuzzleRequest('POST', $url, $this->genHeadersSettings(),
            [
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                        'name' => 'file',
                        'contents' => fopen('data://text/plain;base64,'.$avatar, 'r'),
                        'filename' => $user->getId().'.png',
                    ]
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    'authorId' => $user->getId(),
                    'context' => 'avatar',
                    ]
            ]
        );
```

Above code throws error that `Invalid resource type: array`...

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't actually want to use the PSR-7 interface in this case, since you're converting from an old version of Guzzle. You probably want the `$client->request()` method which is mostly compatible with the older Guzzle request style, including the multipart post you're attempting here (see http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#post-form-requests).

If you do insist on switching to the PSR-7 interface, then you need to pass in a `Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface` object or something that can convert to a stream (such as a string), not an array. This is the error you're receiving.

Comment: I get this `You cannot use form_params and multipart at the same time. Use the form_params option if you want to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and the multipart option to send multipart/form-data requests.`